# How to access ajax call's parameters in the success function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing several ajax calls of the following type in a loop:

```
var param1Val = 'will be different in each loop';
var param2Val = 'will be different in each loop';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: someUrl,
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: {
        'param1': param1Val,
        'param2': param2Val
    },
    success: function(result){
        // how to access param1 and param2 here???
    }
});
```

and I need to access somehow the `param1` and `param2` in the `success` part. I can't use the global `param1Val` and `param2Val` variables, because they will have the value of the last loop until I get some response from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a closure you can do this.

```
var successFunc = function(param1Val, param2val) {
     return function(result) {
       // Access param1Val and param2val here, also can access the api result 
     }
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: someUrl,
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: {
        'param1': param1Val,
        'param2': param2Val
    },
    success: successFunc(param1Val, param2val ) 
});
```